# Passing Y/N when executing a remote bat file from command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, psexec

I am trying to execute remote batch file. I could invoke the batch file using PsExec but unable to complete due to **:choice** in the batch file.

Here is the snippet from batch file

```
:choice
set /P c=Are you sure you want to continue [Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :execute_script
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :END
goto :choice
```

which populating question

[image]

I want to handle this question from the command which is like :

```
cmd /c start C:\temp\PSEXEC\PsExec.exe \\server -u username -p password cmd /c (^cd C:\BatchExecutors ^& SnapExecutor.bat location^)
```

Suggestions appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to modify the batch file? If yes, you could call it with an additional input parameter in order to bypass the question if said input parameter is set.

Comment: No. We are not allowed to change batch file.

Comment: `cmd /c start C:\temp\PSEXEC\PsExec.exe \\server -u username -p password cmd /c (^cd C:\BatchExecutors ^& echo y^|SnapExecutor.bat location^)`  ?

Comment: why is the first (and the last ) carret?

Comment: I guess the `(^` part should read `^(`...

Comment: echo Y^| worked. (^ and ^) are just added when testing the command. Thanks @npocmaka

Comment: Can you provide the original batch script ? Knowing the source code can give important information.

Comment: I tried the same script here and it works as intended, provided that the caller is modified like this:

cmd /c start C:\temp\PSEXEC\PsExec.exe \\server -u username -p password cmd /c "cd /D C:\BatchExecutors & SnapExecutor.bat location"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a strange CMD behaviour when 2 batch files have the same label, to bypass the question. But any code prior to the question would be ignored.

To do this, create another batch file with this inside:

```
    call :execute_script
    goto:eof
    :execute_script
    cd /D C:\BatchExecutors
    SnapExecutor.bat %*
```

So what happens here is that this script will call SnapExecutor.bat, but instead of starting from the begining of the script, it will start from :execute_script

The problem now is how to execute this remotely. You might be able to create this script in a remote writable folder using this command:

```
    cmd /c start C:\temp\PSEXEC\PsExec.exe \\server -u username -p password cmd /c "cd /D c:\[temp folder] &echo call :execute_script>temp.bat &echo goto:eof>>temp.bat &echo :execute_script>>temp.bat &echo cd /D C:\BatchExecutors>>temp.bat &echo SnapExecutor.bat %%*>>temp.bat"
```

(This will create the batch file, then you use this to call it:

```
    cmd /c start C:\temp\PSEXEC\PsExec.exe \\server -u username -p password cmd /c "C:\[temp folder]\temp.bat"
```

NOTE:

- Change [temp folder] to a writeable folder on the remote PC.